# hide autocomplete in jquery

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I need to hide the autocomplete of jquery which i select the text it won't hide.plz give some suggestion.
 Note:it's not the jquery  ui 
 this is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#inputString").autocomplete("rpc.php", {
       width:240;                  

    });

  });
```

Comment: Do you want to hide on pressing enter(check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602395/jquery-ui-autocomplete-hide-list-after-hiting-enter)

Comment: not, I told that when i select a particular item from the list, the autocompleter not hide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Autocomplete widgets provides suggestions while you type into the field. Suppose  suggestions are tags for programming languages, give "ja" (for Java or JavaScript). After selecting Javascript by using suggestion dropdown or div it will hides automatically.

Comment: @azarudeenajees: it works automatically and it hides automatically after selecting a value or if you click anywhere on page it will hides automatically.

Comment: I need to hide if i selected something on the list